# is there a way to use destructuring syntax while still making javascript bind work

Tags: javascript

In example below I cannot use param = {a: 1, b:2} or bind will not work as expected. Is there a way to use destructuring somehow while still making bind work ?

```
  function func0(a) {
    doThis(a, this);
  }
  let func;
    
  function main(param) {
    func = func0.bind(param);
    test(param)
  }
  function test(param) {
    param.a = 1;
    param.b = 2;
    //param = {a: 1, b:2} // cannot use this syntax or new param 
    func("test");
  }

  main({});

  function doThis(a, param) {
     console.log(a + JSON.stringify(param,null,2));
  }
```

Comment: _"...or bind will not work as expected."_ - And what _is_ expected...? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: It doesn't appear that destructuring is really necessary or an advantage?

Comment: Also there's no destructuring happening in the question right now. That comment is just an assignment.

Comment: @zer00ne of course it is because Object.assign is heavy ;)

Comment: @user310291 Aha! That's probably why I don't destructure much is because I prefer to use `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about composition, not destructuring:

```js
function func0(a) {
    doThis(a, this);
}
let func;

function main(param) {
    func = func0.bind(param);
    test(param)
}
function test(param) {
    Object.assign(param, {a: 1, b: 2});
    func("test");
}

main({});

function doThis(a, param) {
 console.log(a + JSON.stringify(param,null,2));
}
```

Comment: I wanted a LIGHT SYNTAX not something heavy like Object.assign ;)

Comment: So it must not exist.

Comment: @user310291 It may feel heavy when dealing with only two keys, on complex objects it feels light like a feather ;)

Comment: @user310291 Why didn't you mention that you don't want to use `Object.assign()` _in the question_? Why do you talk about destructuring when you obviously know that `Object.assign()` is a possible solution, which does the exact opposit of destructuring? And why is this, an `Object.assign()` solution, the accepted answer?

Comment: @Andreas I mean a syntax SIMILAR or AS SIMPLE as destructuring.